# Pandas : Merge two dataframe where the keys are different

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe, one store the values and another stores the weight Key of value dataframe is : [Symbol, Date, Hour] and for the weight dataframe is [Symbol, Date].

```
In [8]: value_df = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol':['S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S3'],
             'Date' : [20150101,20150101, 20150101, 20150102,20150101,20150102,20150103],
             'Hour' : [8,9,10,8,8,8,8],
             'value' : [10,10.1,10.2,11,100,101,300]})

In [9]: value_df
Out[9]: 
       Date  Hour Symbol  value
0  20150101     8     S1   10.0
1  20150101     9     S1   10.1
2  20150101    10     S1   10.2
3  20150102     8     S1   11.0
4  20150101     8     S2  100.0
5  20150102     8     S2  101.0
6  20150103     8     S3  300.0

In [10]: weight_df = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol': ['S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3'], 'Date':[20150101,20150102,20150103] * 3,'Weight': [0.8,0.9,1,1,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5]})

In [11]: weight_df
Out[11]: 
       Date Symbol  Weight
0  20150101     S1     0.8
1  20150102     S1     0.9
2  20150103     S1     1.0
3  20150101     S2     1.0
4  20150102     S2     1.0
5  20150103     S2     1.0
6  20150101     S3     0.5
7  20150102     S3     0.5
8  20150103     S3     0.5
```

I would like to merge these two tables, and add weight column to the value_df It should be an Cartesian product. For Instance:

```
       Date  Hour Symbol  value weight
0  20150101     8     S1   10.0 0.8
1  20150101     9     S1   10.1 0.8
2  20150101    10     S1   10.2 0.8 
3  20150102     8     S1   11.0 0.9
4  20150101     8     S2  100.0 1.0
5  20150102     8     S2  101.0 1.0 
6  20150103     8     S3  300.0 0.5
```

Challenge here is because of the additional 'Hour' column.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the "challenge".  A simple merge already gives your desired output:

```
>>> pandas.merge(value_df, weight_df, on=['Date', 'Symbol'])
       Date  Hour Symbol  value  Weight
0  20150101     8     S1   10.0     0.8
1  20150101     9     S1   10.1     0.8
2  20150101    10     S1   10.2     0.8
3  20150102     8     S1   11.0     0.9
4  20150101     8     S2  100.0     1.0
5  20150102     8     S2  101.0     1.0
6  20150103     8     S3  300.0     0.5
```